# Spark Dataset with dynamically typed/struct column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a spark Dataset with known columns that therefor can be "casted" as a Dataset of a case class.

e.g.

```scala
case class Record(id: string, occurredAt: Long, jsonBody: String)
```

I know make a new column which is the parsed json body, that is dynamically typed based on a given schema.

How to represent this dynamically typed column in a Dataset? Is there a "Struct" type to use? If I use `Any` does it retain the schema?

```scala
case class ParsedRecord(id: string, occurredAt: Long, jsonBody: String, parsedBody: ???)
```

Answer (score 0):

reflect the schema on a case class, and the type will be of the same type as the case class

```
class InnerObj(val a: Int, val b: String)

case class ParsedRecord(id: string, occurredAt: Long, jsonBody: String, parsedBody: InnerObj)
```

Comment: That would indeed be easy :D 

But the schema is coming from config, so I don't know the case class structure to use as it is dynamic (different every time), so looking so something to manage this fact.

For context, I am very comfortable with Scala, that is not the issue :) Just know many Spark users aren't so worth clarifying.